# PHP/PAM to change user password?

Tags: php, linux, passwords, pam

Are there any working packages to change a linux user passwords using PHP?

I've tried using PECL:PAM but theres an error when it tries to change the password.

Edit:

PHP code:

```
echo pam_chpass($username, $password, $new_pass, &$error) ? 'good' : $error;
```

PHP (echo) output:

```
Permission denied (in pam_authenticate)
```

From /var/log/auth (these are actually from before, the log doesn't seem to be working ATM for some reason yet to be determined):

```
Jun 11 15:30:20 veda php: pam_unix(php:chauthtok): conversation failed
Jun 11 15:30:20 veda php: pam_unix(php:chauthtok): password - (old) token not obtained
Jun 11 15:30:20 veda php: pam_winbind(php:chauthtok): valid_user: wbcGetpwnam gave WBC_ERR_DOMAIN_NOT_FOUND
```

Other:

Sorry for the lack of details before, I was really tired when I posted the question but thats still a crappy excuse.

Comment: "theres an error when it tries to change the password" -- what error?  You've just gone to the doctor's office and told him "It hurts," but won't tell him where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of research online, I wasn't able to find a super good option so I'm implemented this hack. It uses [this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/change-linux-or-unix-system-password-using-php-script.html) for changing passwords using PHP.

I'm also using the [PECL:PAM package](http://pecl.php.net/package/PAM) to add a little verification.

This page is on a secure HTTPS folder (automatic redirect via .htaccess)

```
<?php

$messages = array();

function change_password ($user, $currpwd, $newpwd) {

    // Open a handle to expect in write mode
    $p = popen('/usr/bin/expect','w');

    // Log conversation for verification
    $log = '/tmp/passwd_' . md5($user . time());
    $cmd .= "log_file -a \"$log\"; ";

    // Spawn a shell as $user
    $cmd .= "spawn /bin/su $user; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"Password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$currpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"$user@\"; ";

    // Change the unix password
    $cmd .= "send \"/usr/bin/passwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"(current) UNIX password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$currpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"Enter new UNIX password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$newpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"Retype new UNIX password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$newpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"passwd: password updated successfully\"; ";

    // Commit the command to expect & close
    fwrite($p, $cmd); pclose ($p);

    // Read & delete the log
    $fp = fopen($log,r);
    $output = fread($fp, 2048);
    fclose($fp); unlink($log);
    $output = explode("\n",$output);

    return (trim($output[count($output)-2]) == 'passwd: password updated successfully') ? true : false;
}

function process_post() {

    if ((!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) 
        || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === FALSE)) {

        echo "GO AWAY!";
        exit();
        return FALSE;

    }

    global $messages;

    $username           = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password_current   = trim($_POST['password_current']);
    $password_new       = trim($_POST['password_new']);
    $password_confirm   = trim($_POST['password_confirm']);

    // Check for blanks
    if ($username == '' || $password_current == '' || $password_new == '' || $password_confirm == '') {
        array_push(&$messages, "ERROR: You cannot leave any field empty.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Check username
    if (!ctype_alnum($username)) {
        array_push(&$messages, "ERROR: You've entered an invalid username.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Check to see if new password is correctly typed
    if ($password_new != $password_confirm) {       
        array_push(&$messages, "ERROR: New Password and Confirmation do not match.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Check if current password is valid (not really neccessary)
    if (!pam_auth($username, $password_current, &$error, FALSE)) {
        if (trim($error) == "Permission denied (in pam_authenticate)")
            array_push(&$messages, "ERROR: You've username/password was not accepted.");    
        else
            array_push(&$messages, "ERROR: " . $error);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (change_password ($username, $password_current, $password_new))
        array_push(&$messages, "Password Successfully Changed");
    else 
        array_push(&$messages, "ERROR: Password change failed.");

}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') process_post();


?><html>
<head>


<title>Passwords</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

label {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

input {
    float: left;
}

br {
    clear: both;
}

.message {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.error {
    color:#C00;
}


</style>

</head>


<body>

<h2>Change Passwords</h2>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="post">

<fieldset>

<? if (count($messages) != 0) { 

    foreach ($messages as $message) { ?>

<p class="message<?= ((strpos($message, 'ERROR:') === FALSE) ? '' : ' error') ?>"><?= $message ?></p>

<? } } ?>

<label>Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username" /><br />

<label>Current Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password_current" /><br />

<label>New Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password_new" /><br />

<label>Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password_confirm" /><br />

<input type="reset" value="Reset" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</fieldset>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

I also have this question/answer posted in https://serverfault.com/questions/150306/how-to-let-users-change-linux-password-from-web-browser/152409#152409

Comment: Please read my notes below to be able to configure PAM with PHP correctly and handle all the problems that might come up when trying to run the above code.

Comment: Both versions of the script require that the users whose passwords are to be changed have valid shells. Due to the use of `su` the scripts do not work for users with disabled shells.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer posted by wag2369, make sure to perform the following:

Install pear which is the extension manager for PHP:

```
yum install pear
```

Install pam-devel from yum

```
yum install pam-devel
```

Install the PHP PAM extension

```
pecl install --alldeps PAM
```

--alldeps: Means automatically install all dependencies

Modify the file `/etc/php.ini` and enter the following:

```
extension=pam.so
pam.servicename="php"
```

Do the following to allow PAM php service:

```
cd /etc/pam.d
ln -s login /etc/pam.d/php
```

Restart apache:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

/etc/shadow should be readable (this is a security hole, rethink please)

```
chmod g+r,o+r /etc/shadow
```

Install expect if not already installed

```
yum install expect
```

Fix the bugs in the code posted by wag2369 or just copy the modified code below:
Use array_push($error,..) instead of array_push(&$error, ...)
'passwd: password updated successfully' should not be used, use
'passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.' to check instead.

```
<?php
$messages = array();

function change_password ($user, $currpwd, $newpwd) {

    // Open a handle to expect in write mode
    $p = popen('/usr/bin/expect','w');

    // Log conversation for verification
    $log = '/tmp/passwd_' . md5($user . time());
    $cmd = "";
    $cmd .= "log_file -a \"$log\"; ";

    // Spawn a shell as $user
    $cmd .= "spawn /bin/su $user; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"Password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$currpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"$user@\"; ";

    // Change the unix password
    $cmd .= "send \"/usr/bin/passwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"(current) UNIX password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$currpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"Enter new UNIX password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$newpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"Retype new UNIX password:\"; ";
    $cmd .= "send \"$newpwd\\r\"; ";
    $cmd .= "expect \"passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.\"; ";

    // Commit the command to expect & close
    fwrite($p, $cmd); pclose ($p);

    // Read & delete the log
    $fp = fopen($log,'r');
    $output = fread($fp, 2048);
    fclose($fp); unlink($log);
    $output = explode("\n",$output);

    return (trim($output[count($output)-2]) == 'passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.') ? true : false;
}

function process_post() {

    if ((!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) 
        || (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) === FALSE)) {

        echo "GO AWAY!";
        exit();
        return FALSE;

    }

    global $messages;

    $username           = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password_current   = trim($_POST['password_current']);
    $password_new       = trim($_POST['password_new']);
    $password_confirm   = trim($_POST['password_confirm']);

    // Check for blanks
    if ($username == '' || $password_current == '' || $password_new == '' || $password_confirm == '') {
        array_push($messages, "ERROR: You cannot leave any field empty.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Check username
    if (!ctype_alnum($username)) {
        array_push($messages, "ERROR: You've entered an invalid username.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Check to see if new password is correctly typed
    if ($password_new != $password_confirm) {       
        array_push($messages, "ERROR: New Password and Confirmation do not match.");
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Check if current password is valid (not really neccessary)
    $error = '';
    if (!pam_auth($username, $password_current, $error, FALSE)) {
        if (trim($error) == "Permission denied (in pam_authenticate)")
            array_push($messages, "ERROR: Your username/password was not accepted.");    
        else
            array_push($messages, "ERROR: " . $error);
        return FALSE;
    }

    if (change_password ($username, $password_current, $password_new))
        array_push($messages, "Password Successfully Changed");
    else 
        array_push($messages, "ERROR: Password change failed.");

}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') process_post();


?><html>
<head>


<title>Passwords</title>

<style type="text/css">

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

label {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

input {
    float: left;
}

br {
    clear: both;
}

.message {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.error {
    color:#C00;
}


</style>

</head>


<body>

<h2>Change Passwords</h2>

<form action="<?= $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="post">

<fieldset>

<? if (count($messages) != 0) { 

    foreach ($messages as $message) { ?>

<p class="message<?= ((strpos($message, 'ERROR:') === FALSE) ? '' : ' error') ?>"><?= $message ?></p>

<? } } ?>

<label>Username: </label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="halaluya" /><br />

<label>Current Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password_current" value="dev0te@m" /><br />

<label>New Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password_new" value="123" /><br />

<label>Confirm Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password_confirm" value="123" /><br />

<input type="reset" value="Reset" /> <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</fieldset>


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: +1 for php.ini setting and chmod, this article is the most detailed one which I've searched in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Changing PAM passwords from PHP directly, requires to much access to your system files and services. This is because PAM by default uses the pam_unix module, that stores user credentials in system files owned by root. A good way to overcome this problem, is to setup PAM to use the pam_ldap module. This way PAM with authenticate users using an LDAP server. Then from PHP you can bind to the LDAP server using the user credentials and change his password. Authorization for such a modification will can be taken care of by the LDAP authorization mechanism. (Your application should also enforce authorization rules, in order to provide layered security)

The above configuration is not trivial. You must first setup an LDAP server, then migrate all your user data from system files (passwd, shadow) to the LDAP directory. (there are automated tools for that). And finally you must install and setup the pam_ldap module. Any misconfigurations in the above process can lead to serious security issues.

Please, also note that this way you will be exposing the LDAP server to the web through your application. Any security issues that may affect LDAP authentication or authorization mechanisms will also affect your system security.

Resources:

Using LDAP to store POSIX accounts:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-openldap/

Setup PAM to use LDAP for authentication:

http://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/PAM

Comment: You mentioned there are automated tools for moving over to LDAP. Do you have any links to those?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any working packages to change a linux user passwords using PHP?

This is really, really dangerous. Assuming you understand the risks then you'll realise that you need to build a number of constraints before applying the change which must be implemented in the privilege level which allows passwords to be changed - i.e. the code to run this must be a standalone executable with either setuid executoin or called via sudo from your php code.

Of course there's no reason that the standalone code couldn't be written in PHP, other than the fact that the (at least, the last time I looked at this) the PAM bindings in PHP were rather immature,

You might want to have a look at the chpasswd program (available on Redhat and some others distros) or use proc_open('/usr/bin/passwd'... and read and respond to the prompts correctly.

HTH

C.

Comment: I was looking for something so that a user can change their own password. Wouldn't it be using that own user's permissions to attempt to the login and password change?

Comment: Erk! If you don't understand why this is not working, then you probably shouldn't be messing with it until you've read a lot more about how authentication and permissions work on a posix system. And you MUST not allow a web based form the privileges required to change passwords. The guys who wrote webmin are competent programemrs - and they got it wrong multiple times. Only root can change someone else's password. To change your own password then it still needs to start as root then seteuid().

Comment: Then I guess I'll go with proc_open. I just waned to have a better check.

Comment: But I still don't understand the why proc_open would be better than a PAM binding.

Comment: Could you give some clarification as to how proc_open would work? I can't figure out its pipes part since passwd doesn't use stdin or stdout.

Comment: "passwd doesn't use stdin or stdout" - who told you that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use RSBAC passwords.

```
$ret = system("echo \"newpass newpass\" | rsbac_password -n");

if ($ret)
    echo "fail.";
else
    echo "done!";
```

So much easier.