# security concerns regarding accessing shadow password file from php

Tags: php, linux, user-accounts

I wrote this function in php to check user/pass against account on linux server. It works fine, but I am concerned a little about security.

```
/*    Need to add www-data to group shadow (and restart apache)
        $ sudo adduser www-data shadow
        $ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
      Needs whois to be installed to run mkpasswd
        $ sudo apt-get install whois
      Assumes that sha-512 is used in shadow file
*/

function authenticate($user, $pass){
  // run shell command to output shadow file, and extract line for $user
  // then split the shadow line by $ or : to get component parts
  // store in $shad as array
  $shad =  preg_split("/[$:]/",`cat /etc/shadow | grep "^$user\:"`);
  // use mkpasswd command to generate shadow line passing $pass and $shad[3] (salt)
  // split the result into component parts and store in array $mkps
  $mkps = preg_split("/[$:]/",trim(`mkpasswd -m sha-512 $pass $shad[3]`));
  // compare the shadow file hashed password with generated hashed password and return
  return ($shad[4] == $mkps[3]);
}

// usage...
if(authenticate('myUsername','myPassword')){
  // logged in   
} else {
  // not valid user
}
```

1. Does adding www-data to the group shadow have a great security risk on a dedicated server on internal network? (I realise that on shared hosting server it could allow opportunity for hackers to use salt values to crack other user's passwords)
2. Are there any other security concerns with the method I am using?
3. Any suggestions to make it more reliable?

Comment: I'm not deeply familiar with how the shadow group works but giving PHP access to it sounds really dangerous - if I understand it correctly, one PHP script with a broken include call could get an attacker the contents of `/etc/shadow`. Is there no native Unix/Linux command that can do this that you could run selectively?

Comment: Valid point. I do not know a better way to handle this. The other way I tried - which also works is to make a shell script that uses `su` to  log in as the user, and returns an exit code of 0 for success. This can then be called from within php file. It seems a bit overkill, but maybe it is more secure.

Comment: that is a cool idea. Sounds *much* more secure to my ears. I'll convert my comments to an answer with some additional notes

Comment: My feeling is that this might be better suitable on Server Fault - the guys there usually have more insight into this kind of stuff than the SO crowd. Maybe we should vote to migrate?

Comment: Well, why, yes. `/etc/shadow` was conceived specifically because too many applications were accessing `/etc/passwd` directly (When it still contained the passwords). Granting Apache access is anything but sensible.

Comment: If you can change settings on your system, then I'd recommend a PHP extension for this task instead. [PHP/PAM to change user password](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032785/php-pam-to-change-user-password) or indirect access via an LDAP setup.

Comment: You can as well ask about the shadow file on the linux SO site. If your question is clear, you normally get profound and constructive answers. Often this turns into learning a lot of stuff, but that's not a downside in my eyes but the power of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not deeply familiar with how the shadow group works but giving PHP access to it sounds really dangerous - one PHP script with a broken `include` call could get an attacker the contents of `/etc/shadow`. While that's not tantamount to gaining root access, having the encrypted passwords in the open is still nasty, of course.

If there is no native Unix/Linux command that can authenticate a user
 that you could run selectively, I think your idea

> The other way I tried - which also works is to make a shell script that uses su to log in as the user, and returns an exit code of 0 for success. This can then be called from within php file.

sounds much, much better, as it doesn't necessitate opening access to any higher-level resources. You may just have to set up some kind of rate limiting so an attacker can't disable local user accounts by doing thousands of failed login attempts on them.

Comment: I think this is the way to go. I had more of a look around, and other people tend to be using either php/pam, but often with issues, or shell scripts employing spawn/expect/send to change/check passwords. I will follow suit.